# Rails 4 date_field, min and max year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

I am trying to set a maximum year value for my form using the rails 4 method ''date_field'' Because it seems to be possible for the user to type years bigger than 4 digits.

I've been trying to use it like this, but it does not seem to have any effect.

```
<%= f.date_field :date, style: "height: 30px", min: Time.now.year , max:         Time.now.year + 84 %>
```

Comment: I believe it takes `:min` and `:max` [attributes](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) (search for `date_field`).  This is just a wild guess, however, as I know nothing of Rails.

Comment: tryed this too, instead off "max:", ":max", no effect either way, It still accepts  years like "9999999"

Comment: If you add one more `"9'` to the string, will it accept that, or if you set `:min` to today's date, does it work with that string (with seven `"9"`'s)?

Comment: To be more accurate, it accepts 6 digits. (YYYYYY)
Yes it does work, no effects. But I think it may be possible to set a limit because, one can not set a month bigger than 12 or a month with 3 digits.

Comment: Why not use a `date_select` for that http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
<%= f.date_field :date, min: Date.new(1994, 07, 03), max: Date.today %>
```

I limited the mininmum and max date the user could put using the built-in picker with the methods in Ruby's Date class. The only problem is that this isn't dynamic. And regarding your question of validating the year, I believe browsers do it automatically if it detects the input field with a date type (e.g `<input id="user_date" min="1994-07-03" name="user[birthdate]" type="date">`) even before the user submits the form. Hope this helped.

Edit: Updated `Date.now` to `Date.new`.