# Rails - date_select not allow to choose past date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the following code

```
<%= f.date_select 'event_date', selected: Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 1 %>
```

I want to ban people from choosing data at a min of 5 days from now. and max of 1 year max. How can i set the date and month?

Or should i do this in model validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this answer: [Rails 4 date_field, min and max year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126186/rails-4-date-field-min-and-max-year)

You should be able to give the `min` and `max` dates:

```
f.date_select 'event_date', selected: Date.today, min: 5.days.ago, max: 1.year.from_now
```

Comment: is there a way to add a model based validation as well?

Comment: What do you mean? What validation do you want to add?

Comment: to make sure that the validation on the date on submit is min 5days from now n inside one year on creation of the record.

Comment: You can add this validation in the model with a custom validation. Do you want me to write an example in my answer?

Comment: will try to write it. I was wondering if there can be a validation based on if its it being created or updated for the same field?

Comment: yes, sure, you can create your own validation method, it just has to return `true` or `false` (ask Google with "rails custom validation" for more info)