# How to fix minimum date in date_select field in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I've this app on rails, where one of the form has a date_select field for a model and I'm trying to set a minimum date of today in that date_select field such that a user won't be able to select a date before today.

I'm able to fix start_year of the date_select field using [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) but unable to fix start month and start day for the field because there's not any start_month and start_day attributes available.
Also what if I want to freeze some dates like user cannot select sundays then what to do?

Here's my form field looks like-

```
<%= form.label :Date %>
<%= form.date_select( :daterequired, start_year: Date.current.year,
                                          order: [:day, :month, :year],
                                          :class=>'form-control mb-1', id: :order_daterequired)%>
```

One more question-

If I've this form under the path `app\views\order\_form.html.erb`
and there are many other views in my app for example- `app\views\services\index.html.erb`, `app\views\pages\home.html.erb` all of these have many html.erb files. So my question is **exactly where should I put a Javascript code if i'm using Javascript in any of these files under different views?** Should I create different JS files for each html.erb file or just put all JS code in application.js file?

I know I'm asking for a lot but I'm learning this new framework and facing difficulties, Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, there is this another question, I think is the same answer for yours, [min value in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260326/rails-date-select-not-allow-to-choose-past-date).

For second question, you should use the `app/assets/javascripts` folder, you should follow the namespace, for example:

- controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
- assests/javascripts/admin/users.js

Comment: Okay, so first I wanted a minimum date as today not the default, as in by default date a user can still select the past date. Second, Do I have to create JS files according to controller? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I edit the answer, I linked another that is almost the same.